# Загрузка изображений и отображение без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, ajax

Делаю медиа библиотеку на сайт (как на wordpress), и мне нужно через ajax загружать фотографии в нее.
Но для того чтобы увидеть новое загруженное фото нужно перезагрузить страницу.
Как показывает загруженные фото без перезагрузки?

index.php

```
<? 
   $files = glob('uploads/*.jpg');
   usort($files, function ($a, $b)
     {
       return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
     });

   foreach ($files as $file)
    {
     printf(' <img  src="%1$s" style="cursor:pointer" class="gallery_img">', $file, date('F d Y, H:i:s', filemtime($file)));
    }
?>

<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".txt,image/*">
        <a href="#" class="upload_files button">Загрузить файлы</a>
        <div class="ajax-reply"></div>
    </div>

<script>
(function($){

var files; // переменная. будет содержать данные файлов

// заполняем переменную данными файлов, при изменении значения file поля
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){
    files = this.files;
});


// обработка и отправка AJAX запроса при клике на кнопку upload_files
$('.upload_files').on( 'click', function( event ){

    event.stopPropagation(); // остановка всех текущих JS событий
    event.preventDefault();  // остановка дефолтного события для текущего элемента - клик для <a> тега

    // ничего не делаем если files пустой
    if( typeof files == 'undefined' ) return;

    // создадим данные файлов в подходящем для отправки формате
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each( files, function( key, value ){
        data.append( key, value );
    });

    // добавим переменную идентификатор запроса
    data.append( 'my_file_upload', 1 );

    // AJAX запрос
    $.ajax({
        url         : './submit.php',
        type        : 'POST',
        data        : data,
        cache       : false,
        dataType    : 'json',
        // отключаем обработку передаваемых данных, пусть передаются как есть
        processData : false,
        // отключаем установку заголовка типа запроса. Так jQuery скажет серверу что это строковой запрос
        contentType : false,
        // функция успешного ответа сервера
        success     : function( respond, status, jqXHR ){

            // ОК
            if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                // файлы загружены, делаем что-нибудь

                // покажем пути к загруженным файлам в блок '.ajax-reply'

                var files_path = respond.files;
                var html = '';
                $.each( files_path, function( key, val ){
                     html += val +'<br>';
                } )

                $('.ajax-reply').html( html );
            }
            // error
            else {
                console.log('ОШИБКА: ' + respond.error );
            }
        },
        // функция ошибки ответа сервера
        error: function( jqXHR, status, errorThrown ){
            console.log( 'ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ' + status, jqXHR );
        }

    });

});


})(jQuery)
</script>
```

submin.php

```
if( isset( $_POST['my_file_upload'] ) ){  
    // ВАЖНО! тут должны быть все проверки безопасности передавемых файлов и вывести ошибки если нужно

    $uploaddir = './uploads'; // . - текущая папка где находится submit.php

    // cоздадим папку если её нет
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    $files      = $_FILES; // полученные файлы
    $done_files = array();

    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        $file_name = cyrillic_translit( $file['name'] );

        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) ){
            $done_files[] = realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" );
        }
    }

    $data = $done_files ? array('files' => $done_files ) : array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.');

    die( json_encode( $data ) );
}

function cyrillic_translit( $title ){
    $iso9_table = array(
        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Ѓ' => 'G',
        'Ґ' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Є' => 'YE',
        'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'Ѕ' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J',
        'Ј' => 'J', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'YI', 'К' => 'K', 'Ќ' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L', 'Љ' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'Њ' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T',
        'У' => 'U', 'Ў' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'TS',
        'Ч' => 'CH', 'Џ' => 'DH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SHH', 'Ъ' => '',
        'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA',
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'ѓ' => 'g',
        'ґ' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'є' => 'ye',
        'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'ѕ' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j',
        'ј' => 'j', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'к' => 'k', 'ќ' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l', 'љ' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'њ' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
        'у' => 'u', 'ў' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'ts',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'џ' => 'dh', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'shh', 'ъ' => '',
        'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    );

    $name = strtr( $title, $iso9_table );
    $name = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9\'_\-\.]~', '-', $name );
    $name = preg_replace('~\-+~', '-', $name ); // --- на -
    $name = preg_replace('~^-+|-+$~', '', $name ); // кил - на концах

    return $name;
}
```

Comment: Зачем перезагружать страницу если ajax-запрос отдает (ну или должен отдавать) пути к вновь загруженным файлам?

Comment: @u_mulder 
Фото не выводятся. Галерея выводит только фото которые были при загрузке самой страницы

Comment: @u_mulder Как правильно сделать такую ​​медиа библиотеку?.
 Алгоритма будет достаточно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При загрузке файла, перед отправкой ajax-запроса можно прочитать данные файла с помощью FileReader.readAsDataURL() и записать их в атрибут src тега img:

```js
if(files[0]) {
    var reader = FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) { // При загрузке данных файла в FileReader мы загружаем их в элемент img
        $('.gallery-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // Данная функция считывает данные в форме base64 и загружает их в FileReader
}
```

Comment: Немного не по теме, но подскажите, могу ли я загрузить видео на страницу посредствам ajax, вот вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1363354/423786